# lightGallery won't work with <li>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I was trying to get `lightGallery` by Sachin Choolur on my WordPress website and trying to get it dynamically. It almost worked but my slider gets in the way of the lightGallery.

lightGallery would work only if I remove the `li` tags otherwise it won't work. But if I remove the `li` tag there won't be a slider anymore :/ And if I add class to the `li` tags like:

```
<li class="LightGallery LightGalleryDefault">
```

then it would show individual images and not as a gallery.

https://www.realtyscale.com/crescent-bay-parel/#floor-plans

I edited the template PHP.

```
<ul id="lightgallery" class="LightGallery LightGalleryDefault">
   <?php foreach ( $images as $id => $url ) : ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $url ); ?>" >
      <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $id, 'thumbnail' ); ?> </a> 
   </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: seems like fancybox is getting in the way of your lightgallery implementation. Have you tried removing it from this particular section?

Comment: @dommmm Fancybox isn't getting in the way really, it just shows up. There can't be <li> before <a href> if you want to show lightGallery.   I've changed the <ul> to div and removed <li> now lightGallery works, but I can't have a slider anymore. You can check.

Comment: _“lightGallery would work only if I remove the `li` tags otherwise it won't work”_ - https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/html-markup.html: _“LightGallery does not force you to use any kind [of] markup. You can use almost any kin(d) of markup with the help of `selector` setting.”_

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your website and found that on clicking the plan image it opens up the gallery which slider and the fancy box on top of it. Please do disable the fancy box for these slider images .

Because if i close the fancy box and check the slider below that it works perfectly. You fancy box which appears on top of slider is disabling the click action for underlying slider arrows.

Hope this can solve the issue